# How to prevent ItemTemplate and AlternatingItemTemplate from creating newlines

Tags: asp.net, listview, newline, itemtemplate

In aspx, using either a `ListView`, `Repeater`, or any of the other standard controls that are listed under the visual studio 2010 data toolbox: My data source is simply a set of records made up of ID, title, first_name, last_name, degree. I am trying to print them on a single line (going to a newline when the end of a line is reached, not necessarily by a new record), however, the `ItemTemplate` and `AlternatingItemTemplate` seems to print each record as a newline. Is there a way to get rid of that automatic newline? (I tried `ItemSeparatorTemplate`, but that didn't work)

I don't think that it is necessary, but I figured that I'll just give you the code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <a href='#<%# Eval("ID") %>' /><%# Eval("title")%> <%# Eval("first_name")%> <%# Eval("last_name")%> <%# Eval("degree")%></a>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <AlternatingItemTemplate>
         <a href='#<%# Eval("ID") %>' /><%# Eval("title")%> <%# Eval("first_name")%> <%# Eval("last_name")%> <%# Eval("degree")%></a>
     </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Datalaist and make RepeatDirection="Horizontal".

```
<asp:DataList ID="datalist1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"></asp:DataList>
```

Comment: the repeatDirection formats it so that the title is on top of the first name which is on top of the last name which is on top of the degree. Then it places the next record on the same line so that all titles share a line and all first_names share another line. The format that I am looking for is "Dean John Doe Ph.D., Professor Jane Smith M.D." etc.

Comment: If you use RepeatDirection="Horizontal" then all the records (row wise) comes in a single line. Please run it and check the output.

Comment: My bad, apparently I was displaying the anchors in block (after switching to inline, your solution worked)

Comment: I like, but unfortunately I do not have enough rep points to upvote